# Update a column to the row number in a group by SQL

Tags: sql, database, position

The current database I am working with has a table where the defined positions have gone out of order.
I have the following query which can allow me to update the position to the Row Number (RN) but only for a single group of objects with the ParentId

```
SELECT id, ParentId, Position, Title, -1+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Position]) as RN
FROM Objects
where ParentId = 4390
```

[image: SQL results screenshot]

However there are multiple ParentId Groups.

My question is how can this query be applied to the entire Object table while keeping these groupings and row number increments correct?

I know I could use a cursor to loop through a list of the ParentIds but this feels very inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `PARTITION BY`

```
SELECT id
    ,ParentId
    ,Position
    ,Title
    ,-1+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY [Position]) as RN
FROM Objects
```

to update i would use a CTE

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT id
        ,ParentId
        ,Position
        ,Title
        ,-1+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY [Position]) as NewPosition
    FROM Objects
) 
UPDATE CTE 
SET Position = NewPosition 
WHERE Position <> NewPosition
```

Comment: That's great thanks, I now have the data for all objects, what would the syntax be to update each object with their corresponding RN?

Comment: depends on what DBMS you are using.

Comment: I am using Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS V18.4)

Comment: I updated my answer, the where is optional, but helps reduce the number of writes done to the table.